# Mi codigo solo funciona la primera vez que lo ejecuto

Tags: c++, dev-c++

soy nuevo en c++ y tengo el siguiente problema, el codigo de abajo en c++ pide cuatro float que son cuatro notas, saca el promedio de esas cuatro notas e imprime un mensaje de acuerdo a si esta aprobado o no.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
float nota1, nota2, nota3, nota4;

cout << "Ingrese la primera nota: " <<endl;
cin >> nota1;
cout << "Ingrese la segunda nota: " <<endl;
cin >> nota2;
cout << "Ingrese la tercera nota: " <<endl;
cin >> nota3;
cout << "Ingrese la cuarta nota: " <<endl;
cin >> nota4;

float promedio = (nota1+nota2+nota3+nota4)/4;

if(promedio < 3.0)
{
    cout << "No aprobado"<<endl;
}

else if(promedio >=3 && promedio <= 3.5)
{
    cout<< "En este momento no tiene aprobada la materia de tecnología, pero tiene la oportunidad de recuperar."<<endl;
}
else if(promedio > 3.5)
{
    cout<< "Aprobado"<<endl;    
}

}
```

El programa funciona bien, pero unicamente cuando lo compilo y ejecuto la primera vez, cuando lo cierro y abro de nuevo el archivo  .exe al momento de imprimir el resultado se cierra repentinamente sin que pueda ver el resultado. pd: El compilador que uso es dev c++.

Comment: Y si lo ejecutas desde la consola (línea de comandos o "símbolo del sistema") ¿que ocurre? ¿Se cierra la ventana? ¿Muestra algún error?

Comment: Si funciona! Cuando lo ejecuto varias veces desde cmd si funciona. Cuando lo abro con doble click al icono no. Sabes por que será?

Comment: El programa se cierra al terminar, pued s obligarle a que espere como dice @Tejada, por ejemplo con un system("pause");

Comment: Lo normal es que se cierre al terminar, si lo ejecutas desde el gui de c++ no la cierra para que veas el resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías agregar una pausa para que el sistema no se cierre.
Utiliza cin.get() al final del ejercicio para que haga la pausa y puedas visualizar el resultado.

Ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
float nota1, nota2, nota3, nota4;

cout << "Ingrese la primera nota: " <<endl;
cin >> nota1;
cout << "Ingrese la segunda nota: " <<endl;
cin >> nota2;
cout << "Ingrese la tercera nota: " <<endl;
cin >> nota3;
cout << "Ingrese la cuarta nota: " <<endl;
cin >> nota4;

float promedio = (nota1+nota2+nota3+nota4)/4;

if(promedio < 3.0)
{
    cout << "No aprobado"<<endl;
}

else if(promedio >=3 && promedio <= 3.5)
{
    cout<< "En este momento no tiene aprobada la materia de tecnología, pero tiene la oportunidad de recuperar."<<endl;
}
else if(promedio > 3.5)
{
    cout<< "Aprobado"<<endl;    
}
cin.get();//Hará que el sistema haga una pausa después de la ejecución, de esta manera te permitirá ver el resultado obtenido.
}
```

Comment: Probé y tampoco funciona agregándoselo. El problema es que al compilarlo y ejecutarlo por primera vez funciona correctamente , es cuando lo cierro y abro de nuevo el exe , ya no funciona

Comment: Perdón, el cin.get() es al final, editaré el comentario.